# Pure HTML/CSS solution for aligning 3 elements when 2 are dynamically sized?

Tags: html, css, alignment, variable-width, dynamic-sizing

This question takes a bit of explaining.  Please bear with me:

A few months ago, I set up a three-part header for a section on a website.  On the left side of this header there is a Title, the contents of which can change.  To the right side is a Logo, which will always be 150 px wide by 60 px high.  Between them are a set of double lines.  Something like this:

[THIS IS THE TITLE] ======================================= [Logo Here]

This website is responsive, so the overall width of the header is variable.
The Headline must always be on one line.
The div holding the double lines needs to change size to fill the space between the Title and the Logo.

I initially set it up so that the lines resized using media queries and the calc(); function. However, the website has to be compatible all the way down to IE 8, so I ended up writing some JS to get it to work.

Here is a JS fiddle that's essentially mirroring this behavior:
http://jsfiddle.net/55u5mpu2/2/

```js
function sizeLines() { 
var logoSize = document.getElementById("the-logo").offsetWidth; 
var titleWidth = document.getElementById("the-h2-Title").offsetWidth; 
var totalWidth = document.getElementById("entire-Header").offsetWidth; 
var offsetWidth = (logoSize + titleWidth); 
var linesWidth = (totalWidth - offsetWidth - 20) + "px"; 
document.querySelector("#the-lines").style.width = linesWidth;   }

window.onresize = sizeLines;
```

```css
#entire-Header{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height:40px;
}

#the-h2-Title {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#the-lines {
  border-top: 4px solid #000000 !important;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000000 !important;
  height: 1px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 23px;
  min-width: 40px;
}

#the-logo {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 160px;
  max-height: 50px;
  float: right;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="entire-Header">
   <h2 id="the-h2-Title">
      <div id="headlineTextbox">This is a Test Headline</div>
   </h2>
   <div id="the-lines"> &nbsp;</div>
   <img id="the-logo" src="http://placehold.it/150x60">
</div>
```

The issue is, the script takes a long time to load on slow connections, and so the logo is hanging out in a weird spot for a while.  As a result, I'm trying to find a purely CSS/HTML solution to do the same thing that my script is.

There are related questions here, but none of them seems to apply.  I can't put a width on either the title or the lines, because they're both dynamic.

Tables seem to be working okay, but if I put width: auto; on two of the tds, things fail.

Here's an example of an okay table layout I've created:
http://jsfiddle.net/d40a429s/1/

```css
table {width: 100%;}
#test-title {width:20%;}
#lines-here {width:auto;}
#lines-here > div {border-top:4px solid #2a2a2a; border-bottom:4px solid #2a2a2a;height: 1px;}
#test-logo {width: 160px; padding-left: 10px;}
```

```html
<div id="test-Section-Header">
   <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
             <td id="test-title"><h2>Test Title</h2></td>
            <td id="lines-here">
               <div></div>
            </td>
            <td id="test-logo">
               <img src="http://placehold.it/150x60" alt="150 x 60 placeholder logo image">
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

I've tried putting position: absolute; and a top/left or top/right on the logo and title, but I can't get that middle div to resize properly.

So: if anyone made it down here: Any ideas on how I can get this to work without JS?  Or maybe a way to tidy up my JS to make it run faster?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved entirely using HTML and CSS by modifying them both slightly, no need for JavaScript.

Here is my fork of Danield's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/01cxzz2u/3/) - Supports IE8+

**Explanation:**

- Moving `#the-logo` to be the first element within the `#entire-Header` container allows us to float `#the-logo` right, without it wrapping and dropping below the title because it has a "higher priority" when the layout is being calculated.
- Adding a "clearfix" to `#entire-Header` allows us to not be concerned about the title overflowing the space that is allocated by any fixed dimensions. This frees us up to remove the `height` constraint altogether. `#entire-Header` is a block level element (`div`) which means that by default it's width will be 100%  and doesn't need to be explicitly set (unless it has previously been overridden).
- `#the-h2-Title` is the second element within `#entire-Header` and is floated left. Being a block element (`h2`), it will wrap below `#the-logo` as a whole before wrapping the words within itself.
- Now that we have the logo and the title positioned on either side, we can style `#the-lines`. Being a block level element, it will expand horizontally into the available space, which in this case is 100%. To prevent it from extending below the title and the logo, we add `overflow: hidden` or `overflow: auto` to `#the-lines`. This creates a new [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) which makes `#the-lines`'s width narrow to the remaining available space which is calculated between the two floated elements.

  **Caveat:** This will only work as long as the height of `#the-line` is less than that of `#the-logo`, otherwise `#the-line` will wrap below `#the-logo`. This is because it is the third element and it's layout is affected by the first two elements.

The CSS:

```
#entire-Header {
    margin: 1em 0 .5em;
}
/* http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/ */
#entire-Header:before,
#entire-Header:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
#entire-Header:after {
    clear: both;
} 
#the-h2-Title {
    margin: .5em 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#the-lines {
    border-top: 4px solid #000000 !important;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #000000 !important;
    height: 1px;
    /* http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/07/23/overflow-a-secret-benefit/ */
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 23px;
}
#the-logo {
    width: 160px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: right;
}
```

The Markup:

```
<div id="entire-Header">
    <img id="the-logo" src="http://placehold.it/150x60" />
     <h2 id="the-h2-Title">
      <div id="headlineTextbox">This is a Test Headline</div>
   </h2>

    <div id="the-lines"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## With IE8 Support

If you want to keep IE8 support, you can fix slow loading by including the `<script>` tag in the HTML.

```
      ...
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    // JavaScript here
  </script>
</body>
```

## Without IE8 support (IE10+)

If you want a pure CSS solution, use the flexbox. Make the header a flexbox, assign the order to the title, line, and logo, and allow the line to shrink and grow if necessary.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    Title
  </div>
  <div class="line">
    Line
  </div>
  <div class="logo">
    Logo
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
/* CSS */
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.line {
  order: 1;
  flex-shrink: 10000000;
  flex-grow: 10000000;
}
.title {
  order: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
.logo {
  order: 2;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

For more about flexbox, see [this article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and [this useful flexbox playground](http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/).

Answer (score 0):

This can certainly be done with IE8 support

1) Move the fixed width + floated-right image to be the first child

2) Keep `float:left` on the header

3) Set `overflow:hidden` (or auto) on the lines (to establish a new block formatting context)

4) Set `display:inline-block` on the container (to contain the floats)

### [Updated FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/55u5mpu2/10/) (Resize browser to see the effect)

```css
#entire-Header {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}
#the-h2-Title {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
#the-lines {
  border-top: 4px solid #000000 !important;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000000 !important;
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 23px;
}
#the-logo {
  width: 160px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="entire-Header">
  <img id="the-logo" src="http://placehold.it/150x60" />
  <h2 id="the-h2-Title">
      <div id="headlineTextbox">This is a Test Headline</div>
   </h2>
  <div id="the-lines"></div>

</div>
```